# SSD write speed being very slow

Tags: linux, ssd, performance, nvme

I'm using the 970 Pro NVMe PCIe M.2 512GB in my computer which [according to userbenchmark.com](https://ssd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/498971/Samsung-SSD-970-PRO-512GB) has a write speed of 2.2 GB/s. However, on my computer (motherboard: MSI B450 Gaming Pro Carbon AC), the write speed only is 0.35 GB/s:

```
$ sudo hdparm -tT --direct /dev/nvme0n1

/dev/nvme0n1:
 Timing O_DIRECT cached reads:   5472 MB in  2.00 seconds = 2737.04 MB/sec
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 Timing O_DIRECT disk reads: 5542 MB in  3.00 seconds = 1847.06 MB/sec
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=1024 conv=fdatasync,notrunc
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 3.06873 s, 350 MB/s
$ echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 
3
$ dd if=tempfile of=/dev/null bs=1M count=1024 
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 0.426463 s, 2.5 GB/s
```

My computer is running Manjaro and the partition's file system is ext4. It is nowhere near full:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
[...]
/dev/nvme0n1p3  454G  290G  141G  68% /
[...]
```

I noticed the low write speed because copying files takes much longer than I expected. What could be the source of the low write speeds?

Edit: After manually executing the trim command, writing now works with somewhere between 1 and 1.3 GB/s. Still nowhere near the 2.2 GB/s userbenchmark.com talks about, or the 2.3 GB/s the manufacturer states.

Comment: I get something close to your result (1.4GB/s) on a SSD that is supposedly rated for 3GB/s. At these rates SSD speed isn't everything, CPU (read speed of /dev/zero) also comes into play (in addition my SSD is LUKS-encrypted, is this the case for yours?)

Comment: No, it is not encrypted. If I were to buy a second SSD, would I expect the total write speed to be about the current write speed, or about double that?

Comment: SSDs might slow down if they get hot.  Do you have a heat sink on yours?

Comment: @LawrenceC Yes, it is covered with the heat shield that shipped with my motherboard. When I touch the heat shield, it doesn't feel warm.